# How do I use "quotes" in a nested IF function without Excel seeing the numbers in the quotes as text?

Tags: excel, if-statement, timespan, custom-formatting

Here is the function I am trying to trouble shoot.

=IFERROR(IF(OR(B40="",B41="",B42="",C40=""),"Complete the form.",IF(D40<>"",IF(AND(D40<>"",D40<"20:00"),15,IF(AND(D40>="20:00",D40<="24:59"),10,IF(AND(D40>="25:00",D40<="29:59"),5,IF(AND(D40>="30:00",D40<="35:00"),-5,IF(D40>"35:00",-10,""))))))),"")

Context: I am developing a scoring worksheet for a set of training events. We are using a bit of game theory and behavioral economics to encourage specific behaviors in the training activities. This is for a timed drill to see how fast our folks can complete a low-ropes course (e.g., motivational team building activity).

The time stamps in "quotes" (e.g., "20:00") is the amount of time it took our folks to complete the course. This number is being generated by another cell that is taking the difference between the time our folks started and completed the drill (e.g., 10:45 AM - 10:36 AM).

The problem is that putting the quotes around the span of time in my nested IF function is causing Excel to get confused. I think it's looking at them as text instead of numbers. Now here is the kicker. If I remove the quotes Excel would interpret a some of the time spans as row ranges (e.g., 24:59). How can I get the nested IF function to see the span of time in quotes as a time stamp and not as text?

Comment: You could try TIME(hour,minute,second).  For example: TIME(0,20,0).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right "20:00" is a text string not a number - to make it work the way you want you can do either of these:

1. "coerce" the time in quotes, e.g. "20:00"+0, or "20:00"*1
2. use the decimal equivalent - 20 hours is 20/24
3. use VALUE function, e.g. VALUE("20:00")

edit: I was assuming "20:00" was 20 hours, is it 20 minutes? If so you can use TIME function as Tony suggests in his comment.....or do the above but change to "0:20"+0 for 20 minutes..("20:00" will be interpreted by excel as 20 hours...)

Here's a way to do the same using `LOOKUP`....

`=IFERROR(IF(OR(B40="",B41="",B42="",C40=""),"Complete the form.",IF(D40="","",LOOKUP(D40*1440,{0,20,25,30,35;15,10,5,-5,-10}))),"")`